# Select statement in If block in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Following is my PL/SQL block:

```
DROP TYPE t_tf_tab;
DROP TYPE t_tf_row;

CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  zipzone_id NUMBER, 
       beginzipcode NUMBER, 
       endzipcode NUMBER, 
       cu_rate number,
       st_rate number,
       su_rate number
);


CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace
FUNCTION get_tab_ptf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab PIPELINED IS
    zip_id1 number;
    zip_id2 number;
    begin_zip number;
    end_zip number;
    rowcount number;
    rec  t_tf_row;
BEGIN

 select count(*) into rowcount from GSW_ZIP_ZONES;
    select min(ZIPZONE_ID) into zip_id1 from GSW_ZIP_ZONES;
    zip_id2 :=zip_id1 +1;

     select ENDZIPCODE into end_zip from GSW_ZIP_ZONES where ZIPZONE_ID=zip_id1;
    select BEGINZIPCODE into begin_zip from GSW_ZIP_ZONES where ZIPZONE_ID=zip_id2;

  FOR counter in 1..rowcount 

   LOOP 
    if((begin_zip-end_zip)>1) THEN    
    SELECT z.ZIPZONE_ID, z.BEGINZIPCODE, z.ENDZIPCODE, z.TAXING_CODE_ID, g.su_rate
    into rec
    from SBXEXT.GSW_ZIP_ZONES z
    join gsw_geocodes g on z.taxing_code_id= g.taxing_code_id where ZIPZONE_ID in (zip_id1,zip_id2);  

    PIPE ROW (rec);
    end if;

    zip_id1 :=zip_id1 + 1;
    zip_id2 :=zip_id2 + 1;


    END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
```

I am getting the error after If statement. The error is in the Select statement telling that the select statement would be ignored. I don't know how to use the Select statement in If block. Please help.

Comment: Share us the error message please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you use `INTO` keyword at last.. It has to be next to `SELECT`.

Add this to `DECLARE`

```
rec  t_tf_row;
```

And then,

```
SELECT z.ZIPZONE_ID, z.BEGINZIPCODE, z.ENDZIPCODE, z.TAXING_CODE_ID, g.su_rate
into rec
from SBXEXT.GSW_ZIP_ZONES z
join gsw_geocodes g on z.taxing_code_id= g.taxing_code_id 
where ZIPZONE_ID in (zip_id1,zip_id2)
```

Comment: I created the types like below:

Comment: DROP TYPE t_tf_tab;
DROP TYPE t_tf_row;

CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  zipzone_id NUMBER, 
       beginzipcode NUMBER, 
       endzipcode NUMBER, 
       cu_rate number,
       st_rate number,
       su_rate number
);


CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;

Comment: Still it is giving error Error(2,48): PLS-00201: identifier 'T_TF_TAB' must be declared

Comment: I have updated my code block, it is giving error in T_TF_TAB, i dont understand why

Comment: You create the `TYPE` and `FUNCTION` with same user or schema?

Comment: then the return should be rec? instead of t_tf_tab?

Comment: No, return is still `t_tf_tab` in declaration.. Where's we pipe every child row of it in our body.. which is of type `t_tf_row`

Comment: Yes same user and schema, i think i am getting garbled at the declaration, i am getting error at that point.

Comment: you gave a `/` after your `create` statement? you got the message `type created`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME='T_TF_TAB'`.. this should return rows, if the type do exists..

Comment: Now again it is giving select statement ignored, i dont understand what is happening, the T_TF_TAB table is created because i get a row in the select from user_objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62439/discussion-between-maheswaran-ravisankar-and-sormita-chakraborty).

Comment: What error you get exactly? Can u paste the full message

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty Joining the [stack chat here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62439/discussion-between-maheswaran-ravisankar-and-sormita-chakraborty) would be easier.

Comment: Error(22,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and Error(24,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values. I am getting these error in the select statements.